# Delegate not called after dismissing controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, presentviewcontroller

I have a Controller A and there is a UIButton, which on click I am presenting a new Controller B. But the problem is that the controller B is first embedded with a NAV. So ultimately I am presenting the UINavigationController.

Now there is a UIButton in Controller B on which the controller will dismiss and a delegate should be passed on controller A with some message

Controller A UIButtonCode

```
- (IBAction)summaryButtonClick:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard* storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* summaryVC=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SummaryNavVC"];

[self presentViewController:summaryVC animated:YES completion:nil];
summaryVC=nil;

}
```

Now Controller B
    .h file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol SummaryViewWhatsNewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) SummaryViewWhatsNew:(NSString*)title;
@end
@interface SummaryViewController :         
UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
id <SummaryViewWhatsNewDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *summaryTableView;
- (IBAction)closeSummaryView:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
//Button Click 
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
 [_delegate SummaryViewWhatsNew:@"Sales Triggers Filter"];
}];
```

I have already made the implementation of delegate in my Controller A
.h

```
@interface ControllerA : UIViewController<SummaryViewWhatsNewDelegate>
```

.m of Controller A

```
#pragma mark -ControllerB Delegate
-(void)SummaryViewWhatsNew:(NSString *)title{
    NSLog(@"Delegate Called");
}
```

In this case I know I haven't provided the **delegate.self** part as I am presenting the NAV controller and not the Controller B

So I made a Object in viewDidLoad and Controller *B and set the delegate to self. But it doesn't work and delegate is never called

On the other hand if I only present the Cntroller B without Navigation and just before presenting I keep the b.delegate=self, it works.

Another alternate can be firing Notifications. But I want to work with delegates.

So is there any way to call the delegate of the presented view controller which is **embedded by Nav**. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: b.delegate=self has to be set, otherwise I doubt it'll work.

Comment: where.?? I cant set b.delegate if I am making an object on UINav to be presented. Just read my last line.

Comment: You have to set in the controller where you are invoking controller B.

Comment: Controller B is embedded with nav..Can you be more detailed on that. Thanks

Comment: Well @SrinivasanN Thanks, I got a solution and posted too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got the answer
We have to fetch the Controller object from NAV

Where I a presenting I just need to add these lines and it worked

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* summaryVC=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SummaryNavVC"];

//Add These lines in order to get the object of Controller B.
// SummaryViewController is my Controller B

SummaryViewController* summary=[[summaryVC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
summary.delegate=self;
[self presentViewController:summaryVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it worked.